# Why do we use the term "such that" instead of just using "and"?

Tags: proof-writing, terminology

Instead of saying "The function $f(x)=2x$ such that $x>0$"
why not just say "$f(x)=2x$ AND $x>0$"
logically it gives the exact same restriction.. so what is the benefit of adding the term "such that" over using logical AND?

Comment: I don't think you would ever even say "The function f(x)=2x such that x>0". What should the sentence mean; something like "The function f defined by f(x) = 2x for x > 0"? Likewise, what does "f(x) = 2x" mean as a logical statement? That the equality holds for all $x$?

Comment: I've never seen that usage of "such that". The main place where I see "such that" is with existential quantifiers: "there exists x such that P(x)".

Comment: "such that" here is incorrect. However, "and" here is incorrect too. Moreover, in general, "such that" and "and" have distinct meanings.

Comment: "Such" and "that" and "and" are not technical terms. Your questions about the English language should be posted on one of the English language stack exchanges.

Comment: @bof disagree. "Such that" is mathematical idiom and its proper use is on topic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would not say ‘The function $f(x)=2x$ such that $x>0$’; it’s very poor usage. So is ‘The function $f(x)=2x$ and $x>0$’. What is meant here is ‘The function $f$ on the set of positive real numbers defined by $f(x)=2x$’. There are shorter, more informal ways to say this, but they don’t include either of your formulations. One could, for example, say ‘The function $f(x)=2x$ restricted to the positive reals’, or even, a bit more sloppily, ‘The function $f(x)=2x$ on $x>0$’.

More generally, when *such that* is used correctly, it can almost never be replaced by *and*. The expression *the object* $X$ *such that* $P(x)$ means *the object* $X$ *with the property* $P$; $P$ is a property of $X$, part of the description of $X$, not some independent statement that can be attached with the logical conjunction *and*.

Comment: So we use "such that" to describe properties? I see.. thanks

Comment: @Pineapple29: Yes: in general you can think of it as shorthand for *with the property that*. You’re welcome.

Comment: I would say that the word 'where' could be a good usage. The function f(x) = 2x where x > 0

Answer (score 13):

For this example I would say "The function $f(x)=2x$ for $x>0$".

Here, "for" is shorthand for "defined for all $x>0$".

Answer (score 1):

Your correct that "such that" isn't appropriate, nor is "and": What we have, essentially, is a conditional:

IF $x\gt 0$, then $f(x) = 2x$

More formally, this can be written:

$$\forall x\Big((x\gt 0) \rightarrow (f(x) = 2x)\Big)$$

Alternatively, if you are working with a specific function and wanting to claim the existence of an $x\gt 0$ for which $f(x) = 2x$, you can write:

There exists an x such that $(x\gt 0$ and $f(x)= 2x)$.

That can be written: $$\exists x( x\gt 0 \land f(x) = 2x)$$